# On iphone, how can i get the system date in the proper format

Tags: iphone, time, format

Based on local user settings, I want to get the correct date format. For example, it could be any of these:

5 Jan 2010
January 5, 2010
1/5/10

And how about on windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `NSDateFormatter` with one of the `NSDateFormatterStyle` styles. It automatically uses the user's locale.

Answer (score 2):

NSDate *selected = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
    strDate =  [format stringFromDate:selected];

Change the format to any thing u want.(M for month, d for day, Y for year, m for minute, h for hour and s for sec)

Comment: Thanks. close but this does not use the current user locale though.